# Angular how to use add form as edit?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple add form like this

```
    <form class="form" [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="floatEmail">Product Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="name" formControlName="name" >
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.name.errors">
                        <small class="form-text text-muted danger" *ngIf="f.name.errors.required" >Please enter a name!</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="floatEmail">Product Arabic Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="arname" formControlName="arname" >
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.arname.errors">
                        <small class="form-text text-muted danger" *ngIf="f.arname.errors.required" >Please enter a arname!</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <label for="placeTextarea">Product Description</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="placeTextarea" rows="3" name="description" formControlName="description" placeholder="Textarea with placeholder"></textarea>
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.description.errors">
                        <small class="form-text text-muted danger" *ngIf="f.description.errors.required" >Please enter a description!</small>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
        -->

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-raised mr-1">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-raised" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      arname: ['', Validators.required],
      description: ['', Validators.required],

  });
  }
  get f() { return this.registerForm.controls; }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;

    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
        return;
    }

    // display form values on success
    console.log(this.registerForm.value);
    var body = this.registerForm.value
    this.http.post("http://itserviceapi.airtechsolutions.pk/api/admin/category/insert", body).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });

}
```

I need to know how can I use this same form as edit?

Mean in the edit I have all these fields which are in input but how can i know it an edit call not add call

I am simply using a router link  like this i need to pass something so i know its edit form or something ?

```
routerLink="/full-layout/edit-form"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is put some ID in your route to recognize that this page is in edit form:

```js
 {
                path: "full-layout/:option",
                component: FullLayoutComponent,
 },
```

Now you can get the ID via route and putting ActivatedRoute in your constructor:

```js
 
    options = this.route.snapshot.params.options
 
    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) { }
    
    functionToAddOrEdit(){
       if(this.option == 1)
         //add
       else
         //edit
    }
```

You can call your route like this:

```js
  constructor(
        private router: Router,
    ) { }
    
    someFunction(){
        this.router.navigate(["full-layout/1"])  //you can put any value that you want to distinguish add and edit
    }
```

Now you know with the variable option if this form is for edit or add

Answer (score 0):

you can pass some parameter flag to the form in edit mode. In the form you can check the flag value and can decide Add Mode or Edit Mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object as ngModel so when you are going to create a new product you can set all fields of the main object to null (in order to change them from the form) and when you edit a product You just clone the product into the ngModel product.

Something like this:

.ts:

```
editProduct(){
   this.formProduct = productToEdit;
}

createProduct(){
   this.formProduct = new Product();
}
```

html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="formProduct.arname" name="arname" formControlName="arname" >
```

That should help solve your problem! :)